# Orleans TestClusterBuilder can't share dependency injection registrations

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-7.0, .net-8.0, orleans

I can't figure out how to share my service registrations between my test code that uses Orleans and the test code that is outside of Orleans. I've spent days trying to figure this out.

My unit tests have their own ServiceCollection where I've registered the services that my application requires. For my experiment, I'm registering one singleton (`Something`).

I'm now adding Orleans' TestClusterBuilder to my unit test. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/implementation/testing), I need to `AddSiloBuilderConfigurator...`.

How do I avoid registering `Something` twice? This feels like a chicken-and-egg situation. Worse still, the `Something` that gets injected in my grains is a different singleton than the `Something` that gets registered in `app`.

This only seems to be a problem in my unit tests. In the main application code, there is no `TestClusterBuilder` and the DI works as expected.

My code looks something like:

```cs
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    var webApplicationBuilder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
    webApplicationBuilder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
        .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(c =>
        {
            c.RegisterType<Something>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
        });


    var app = webApplicationBuilder.Build();

    var testClusterBuilder = new TestClusterBuilder(1);
    testClusterBuilder.AddSiloBuilderConfigurator<TestSiloConfigurations>();
    TestCluster = testClusterBuilder.Build();
    TestCluster.Deploy();
}

public class TestSiloConfigurations : ISiloConfigurator
{
    public void Configure(ISiloBuilder siloBuilder)
    {
        siloBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<Something>();
        });
    }
}
```

For the record, we're using Autofac, but I don't think that matters here.

Comment: I am not familiar with .NET or Orleans but it seems like the TestCluster is a DI enabled environment with some sort of container for storing .NET class instances when running your application. 

If you are configuring services in the TestSiloConfigurations class to make them available to other tests, why not move the app builder and app into the siloBuilder where you add your Something singleton, and then access the app via the silo?